# PowerShell delete folders permanently from Online Archive in Outlook

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a macro in PowerShell to delete a lot of subfolders in the Online Archive. This is the code I'm using to delete them in my personal inbox.

```
$Outlook = New-Object -comobject "Outlook.Application"
$MAPI = $Outlook.getnamespace(“mapi”)
$Folder= $MAPI.GetDefaultFolder(6)
$SubFolder = $Inbox.Folders | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "Test_4*"}
$SubFolder | % {$_.Delete()}
```

Does anyone have a solution to that one?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does variable `$Inbox` come from? As aside: never use curly 'smart-quotes' in code like you do here: `$Outlook.getnamespace(“mapi”)`. Change these into straight quotes.

Comment: It works. I think that's what count. I'm still wondering if there is a way to make this happen, I need to delete all subfolders in my Online Archive.